# NameError: name 'delete' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

**Hello** I have recently been learning python and I was practicing ... I just can't understand the reason for the error as it seems to me that I define inside the buttons.
If someone kindly can help me I would be very grateful

I don't know how to go on anymore and I don't understand where the mistake is, I would like to be able to understand it but I can't do it, can you explain it to me?

```
windows = tk.Tk()
windows.geometry("400x350")
windows.title("Gym Tracker")
windows.resizable(False, False)

frame1 = Frame(windows, width=150, height=30, highlightcolor="white",highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1).place(x=120, y=2)
label1 = Label(windows, text="GYM TRACKER").place(x=150, y=7)
frame2 = Frame(windows, width=500, height=1, highlightcolor="white",highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1).place(x=2, y=45)

labelmes = Label(windows, text="Mese").place(x=110, y=60)
combobox = Combobox(windows, values=['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno','Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre']).place(x=200, y=60)
entry2 = tk.Entry(windows)

labealt = Label(windows, text="Altezza").place(x=110, y=90)
textbox = Text(windows, width=17, height=1).place(x=200, y=90)
entry3 = tk.Entry(windows)

labelpeso = Label(windows, text="Peso").place(x=110, y=120)
textbox = Text(windows, width=17, height=1).place(x=200, y=120)
entry4 = tk.Entry(windows)

labelmmagra = Label(windows, text="Massa Magra").place(x=110, y=150)
textbox = Text(windows, width=17, height=1).place(x=200, y=150)
entry5 = tk.Entry(windows)

labelmgrassa = Label(windows, text="Massa Grassa").place(x=110, y=180)
textbox = Text(windows, width=17, height=1).place(x=200, y=180)
entry6 = tk.Entry(windows)
# Combobox Utente
labelutente = Label(windows, text="Utente").place(x=110, y=210)
combobox = Combobox(windows, values=['Erika', 'Lorenzo']).place(x=200, y=210)
entry7 = tk.Entry(windows)


b1 = tk.Button(windows, text="Importa", command=delete ,width=8,`enter code here`height=1).place(x=170,y=310)
b2 = tk.Button(windows, text="Avanti", width=8,height=1,command=nextpage).place(x=300,y=310)
b3 = tk.Button(windows, text='Salva', width=8, height=1, command=save).place(x=50, y=310)

def delete():
    entry2.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry3.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry4.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry5.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry6.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry7.delete(0, tk.END)

def nextpage():
    labelmes.destroy()
    labealt.destroy()
    labelpeso.destroy()
    labelmmagra.destroy()
    labelmgrassa.destroy()
    labelutente.destroy()
    b1.destroy()
    b2.destroy()
    b3.destroy()
    
def save():
    mese = entry2.get()
    altezza = entry3.get()
    peso = entry4.get()
    mmagra = entry5.get()
    mgrassa = entry6.get()
    utente = entry7.get()
    wb = Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    ws['A1'] = "Mese"
    ws['B1'] = "Altezza"
    ws['C1'] = "Peso"
    ws['D1'] = "Massa Magra"
    ws['E1'] = "Massa Grassa"
    ws['F1'] = "Utente"
    ws['A2'] = mese
    ws['B2'] = altezza
    ws['C2'] = peso
    ws['D2'] = mmagra
    ws['E2'] = mgrassa
    ws['F2'] = utente
    wb.save(r'C:\Users\lricci\Desktop\SERVER\web\Gym Tracker\Gym Tracker v1.0\track.xlsx')
    showinfo("Hai salvato correttamente")
    file = pd.read_excel("track.xlsx")
    all = [file]
    append = pd.concat(all)
    append.to_excel("track.xlsx",index=False)
windows.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
b1 = tk.Button(windows, text="Importa", command=delete ,width=8,`enter code here`height=1).place(x=170,y=310)
```

Attaches the button to the `delete` function, however, at the time you're executing it you haven't *defined* the delete function (you do that slightly later).

Try moving that line below your `def delete():` block.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so it was just a positioning error

Comment: That's my best guess from the information provided. The Exception should give you a line number that's causing the exception. If it's the line I've quoted, it's almost certainly the issue. If it's another line, you may have multiple issues. Fundamentally though, Python does everything on the first pass, unlike some compiled languages (C#/Java) which do multiple passes of a file, meaning position of a method within the file is far less important.